# Python - round off a value

Tags: python, pandas

I tried the following in my Jupyter notebook. When I round off value to 3 decimal points, its showing 3 decimal values. But when I round off to 2 decimal points, its showing 1 decimal value only.

round(64.10343, 4)
output: 64.1034

round(64.10343, 3)
output: 64.103

round(64.10343, 2)
**output: 64.1**

Answer (score 0):

It happens because when you round to two decimal points after rounding 64.10 is left since second decimal is zero, output is not displayed.